# disaster: mouse, wifi and ethernet no longer working after ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Have rebooted and now in broken state.

I am used to wifi breaking and normally I just rebuild the driver but now won't even compile.

I will be trying to work through this by first finding ethernet cable and trying to update things.

If there is an easy revert, please let me know. Limited/awkward access to internet at the moment.

UPDATE: not even ethernet works.

UPDATE: 22.04 jammy.

UPDATE: this is very, very, very bad. I am going to have to re-install everything. It is causing me to reconsider continuing with ubuntu. I've never had something *this* bad before on a simple driver update.

Googling "revert to previous driver" yields nothing.

Is there not some "panic safe mode reboot" option? This should be top hit.

UPDATE: I have managed to reboot esc get to grub menu and boot into previous kernel. Now have internet and mouse.

Need to know what to do next. I have purged nvidia so need to reinstall those. NO idea what is next reasonable thing.

Comment: I think at this point my options are the chuck the whole thing and reinstall

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the installation of Nvidia drivers. The problem - apparently - was a regression in the kernel version installed alongside other updates but independent and UNRELATED to the Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know cause but am now back to working. This is roughly what I did:

- reboot, hit escape, get to grub menu, advanced options, boot into previous kernel
- previous kernel kind of worked, was at least online, was able to run updates, drivers etc, had to reboot a few times. I also purged nvidia drivers at some point.
- finally rebooted into the main (orig) kernel, that was in weird state with graphics drivers but was online at least and mouse worked, again ran several rounds of updates and reboots
- finally had to pull repo and rebuild and reinstall the wifi driver. Reboot again.
- maybe things work now. at least they seem to. GPU etc still not really working but will try to debug that later.